# How do I make a delay between three periods on one line in batch for a text adventure?

Tags: batch-file, delay

I'd like to make three periods show one after the other in, for instance, 3 second intervals.

As in: .(3 seconds).(3 seconds).

Basically I'd like to make an ellipsis that shows more slowly (rather than immediately) for some dialogue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (338 results for https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=batch+echo+one+line search):

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
<nul (set /p x=.)
timeout /t 3 /nobreak > NUL
<nul (set /p x=.)
timeout /t 3 /nobreak > NUL
echo(.
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to get a batch script to sleep is using the command `timeout`.

```
@echo off
echo Hello
timeout /t 3 /nobreak > NUL
echo World
```

This will print 'Hello' then wait for 3 seconds and then print 'World'

Comment: So I did this but the periods are being put one below the other.  Is there any way I could do this in a single row?

Comment: Also, sorry for not being able to describe what I'm trying to do better.  I'm new to programming.